# Skipping empty records in mysql with php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a survey but when I have an empty record in my msql database he just shows an empty question is there a possibility to skip empty records?

```
<?php
session_start();

include "config.php";
connDB();


$some_questions = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM question"));        

if($_POST['next'] && $_SESSION['qnumber'] != '' && $_POST['question'.$_SESSION['qnumber']] != '')
{
    if($_POST['question1']){
        $_SESSION['antwoordjes'] = $_POST['question1'];
    }else{
        $_SESSION['antwoordjes'] .= '|'.$_POST['question'.$_SESSION['qnumber']];
    }
    $_SESSION['qnumber']++;
    $questionnumber = $_SESSION['qnumber']++;
    $sql = "SELECT id, question FROM question WHERE id = '$questionnumber'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($count = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        if($count['question'] == null)
        {
            $_SESSION['qnumber']++;
        }
    }

}

if($_POST['question'.$some_questions] != '' && $_SESSION['qnumber'] >= ($some_questions + 1))
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers (ip,answers,datum) VALUES ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".$_SESSION['antwoordjes']."',NOW())");
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: outro.php");
}

if($_SESSION['qnumber'] == '' || $_SESSION['qnumber'] >= ($some_questions + 1))
{
    $quest = 1;
    $_SESSION['qnumber'] = $quest;
}
else{
    $quest = $_SESSION['qnumber'];
}

$data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT question,answers FROM question WHERE id='".$quest."'"));


$answers = explode('|',$data['answers']);

$quest = stripslashes($data['question']);

if(empty($_POST['atext']))
{

}else{

    $quest = $_POST['hsvraag'];
    $commentary = $_POST['atext'];
    toevoegenOverig($commentary, $quest);
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function disablefield(){ 
if (document.getElementById('yes_radio').checked == 1){ 
document.getElementById('textbox_A').disabled='disabled'; 
document.getElementById('textbox_A').value='';
}else{ 
document.getElementById('textbox_A').disabled=''; 
document.getElementById('textbox_A').value=''; } 
} 
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script> --> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Internet onderzoek</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<table align="left">
</table>
<div class="centrum">
<div class="header">Internetsurvey</div>
<div class="content" id="content">
<div class="balk">Introductie | <span style="color:#000033;">question</span> | end</div>
<br/>
<form method="post" action="vragenv.php">
<?php
$nummer = 1;
foreach($answers as $answer)
{
    echo '<input id="yes_radio" type="radio" name="question'.$_SESSION['qnumber'].'" value="'.$nummer.'" id="answer'.$nummer.'" onChange="disablefield();"/><label for="answer'.$nummer.'">'.$answer.'</label><br />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="hsvraag" value="'.$quest.'"/>';
    $nummer++;
}
?>
</br>
<br/><input type="text" id="textbox_A" required name="atext"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="next" value="next" class="knop" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `$data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT question,answers FROM question WHERE id='".$quest."' AND question <>''"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweak your query.

```
SELECT 
    `id`, 
    `question` 
FROM 
    `question` 
WHERE 
    `id` = '$questionnumber' 
    AND 
    `question` IS NOT NULL 
    AND 
    LENGTH(TRIM(`question`))>1
```